# Textmate Find regex, Replace wild

Tags: regex, replace, textmate-1.5

In [textmate-1.5](/questions/tagged/textmate-1.5) I can use the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) syntax `(.*)` to find both lines in the below use case:

```
<span class="class1"></span>
<span class="class2"></span>
```

Now I want to append more code to each of them so my find query is `span class="(.*)"` and my replace query is `span class="(.*)" aria-hidden="true"` which i had hoped would result in this:

```
<span class="class1" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
<span class="class2" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

but it actually resulted in this:

```
<span class="(.*)" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="(.*)" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

---

Using find/replace (not using column selection which would work for this example but not for the actual situation) is it possible to maintain the area matched by regex in the replace action with a representative wild character or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your replace query as,

```
span class="$1" aria-hidden="true"
```

`$1` would [refer](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) the characters which are present inside group index 1.

Comment: Awesome.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
(<span class="[^"]*")
```

Try this.Replace with `$1 aria-hidden="true"`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/22

Comment: Thanks.  This works as well but changing the find query wasn't necessary as it works either way.

Comment: @dcc dont see a reason why it shouldnt :(...... are you applying the search and replace function both correctly